# APK Tool tutorial Needed

Tags: apk, theming

I have bought and installed the launcher X in my Elelphone P 8000. It is very nice launcher with lots of options. but the developer quit the project and not responding to our requests. I want to randomize the transition effect in the application drawer and also randomize the screen effects like, 'sunny', ' dandrolene', 'rainy' etc on the home screen.  In simple words, how to add the option 'RANDOM' in the transition effects and home screen effects, so that they change automatically at intervals in a random fashion Can anybody kindly give the details how it can be done using APK tool﻿. Secondaly is it possible to make the background of certain applications like Messaging, Whatsapp etc to transparent by editing the XML.file?.

Comment: You know that you might violate copy right

Comment: APK tool is to edit any already published apks as per our wish.. If the developer is not responding to your requests especially after taking your money( actually in the case of X launcher , he is no more available  for any comment for the last 1 year), what we can do , and how it will be an impinge on the copy right. We are not publishing the apk for others to download and take advantage